# SQL Server 2019 Configuration won't connect but Management will

Tags: sql-server

I have an odd situation...

I have my SQL Server 2019 database on encrypted disk (Windows 11) so this is first attached after computer started.

So in the past I would launch SQL Server Configuration Manager and stop server, then start the server. This gives error

"Connect connect to WMI Provider. You do not have permission or the server is unreachable. Note that you can only manage SQL Server 2006 and later servers wit SQL Server Configuration Manager. Invalid class [0x80041010]"

However... SQL Server Management Studio *and* my own software *can* connect my database... So while one might argue there isn't a problem right now, it still worries me...

Any suggestion on how to fix this issue?

Comment: Looks like https://stackoverflow.com/a/51685000/7411885 . Did you uninstall a separate instance of SQL server at some point? https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/sql/tools/error-message-when-you-open-configuration-manager

Comment: I did not uninstall anything. But I will try read the links. Thank you :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please go to below folder using Command Prompt

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\150\Shared
```

That path may vary depending on the installation of SQL Server.

Once you are there, please execute the following command:

```
mofcomp sqlmgmproviderxpsp2up.mof
```

Verify SQL Server Configuration Manager is running fine again.

If that does not work, please consider to repair the SQL Server installation using **[these steps](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/install-windows/repair-a-failed-sql-server-installation?view=sql-server-ver16)**. That won't harm successfully installed components.

Comment: Thank you. This gives error:
Microsoft (R) MOF Compiler Version 10.0.22000.1
Copyright (c) Microsoft Corp. 1997-2006. All rights reserved.
Parsing MOF file: sqlmgmproviderxpsp2up.mof
MOF file has been successfully parsed
Storing data in the repository...
An error occurred while processing item 1 defined on lines 4 - 7 in file sqlmgmproviderxpsp2up.mof:
Error Number: 0x80041003, Facility: WMI
Description: Access denied
Compiler returned error 0x80041003
PS C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\150\Shared>

Comment: Just for reference: 1) I am using my main admin account - the same account used for installing and everything else. 2) I am using Windows PowerShell if that matters.

Comment: Please try to repair the SQL Server instance using this article. It won't harm the others SQL Server components working fine. https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/install-windows/repair-a-failed-sql-server-installation?view=sql-server-ver16

Comment: This worked. (Thank you) I have saved all the files now. And this SO :)

Comment: I am glad it worked for you. Thank you for your feedback.